# If someone doesn't pray, but refrain himself from eating haram food (eg-pork), will it be regarded as good deed?

Tags: halal-haram, salat, islamic-philosophy, deeds

Assalamu Alaikum everyone.

Lets say, there is a sunni muslim named "Farook". Farook believes everything about Islam. But, he does Not pray, due to laziness.

He refrains himself from some haram things, such as- eating haram food, having sex with someone before marriage etc.

Will these deeds have any importance to Allah? or, these deeds have Zero value because he is Not praying.

Please reply asap. Thanks.

Comment: If you don't do some duties while you do others would you expect rewards?

Comment: elaborate please?

Comment: To be a Muslim one must act like a Muslim just believing like a Muslim is not enough. There's no such thing like I take parts of the religion and act upon them and leave others.

Comment: https://legacy.quran.com/2/208

Answer (score 1):

You should know that all deeds count and all deeds are written down and recorded no matter how small they may be. And we will be judged upon anything we did or left on judgement day, as Allah the almighty says.

- > And [for] every person We have imposed his fate upon his neck, and We will produce for him on the Day of Resurrection a record which he will encounter spread open. (13)
  >   [It will be said], "Read your record. Sufficient is yourself against you this Day as accountant." ([17:13-14](https://legacy.quran.com/17/13-14))
- > And the record [of deeds] will be placed [open], and you will see the criminals fearful of that within it, and they will say, "Oh, woe to us! What is this book that leaves nothing small or great except that it has enumerated it?" And they will find what they did present [before them]. And your Lord does injustice to no one. ([18:49](https://legacy.quran.com/18/49))
- > Or do they think that We hear not their secrets and their private conversations? Yes, [We do], and Our messengers are with them recording. ([43:80](https://legacy.quran.com/43/80))
- > And you will see every nation kneeling [from fear]. Every nation will be called to its record [and told], "Today you will be recompensed for what you used to do. (28)
  >   This, Our record, speaks about you in truth. Indeed, We were having transcribed whatever you used to do." ([45:18-29](https://legacy.quran.com/45/28-29))
- > Man does not utter any word except that with him is an observer prepared [to record]. ([50:18](https://legacy.quran.com/50/18))
- > And indeed, [appointed] over you are keepers, (10)
  >   Noble and recording; (11)
  >   They know whatever you do. ([82:10-12](https://legacy.quran.com/82/10-12))
- > So whoever does an atom's weight of good will see it, (7)
  >   And whoever does an atom's weight of evil will see it. ([99:7-8](https://legacy.quran.com/99/7-8))

So we can be certain that none of our deeds will be missed at the day of judgment. But the final judgment on each of us is in the hands of Allah based on the weight of our deeds, so hopefully we may have enough good deeds to enter Jannah.

Note that even if the scholars are in disagreement on whether or not a "Muslim" who doesn't pray actually is a Muslim or should be handled like an apostate all of them hold the opinion that he must be warned in first place, locked-in (by the authorities) and given the chance to pray or even ordered to do this afterwards the views differ between keeping him this way or sentencing him to death. So not praying is rejecting a very important part of the Muslim believe which is even considered as a pillar of Islam (rejecting something ordered by Allah is part of kufr and laziness is not a good excuse). And it is one of the most apparent practices in our religion which one shouldn't take lightly.

Therefore on the other hand it is a sign of nifaaq (hypocrisy) not to pray due to laziness as Allah the almighty says:

- > Indeed, the hypocrites [think to] deceive Allah , but He is deceiving them. And when they stand for prayer, they stand lazily, showing [themselves to] the people and not remembering Allah except a little, ([4:142](https://legacy.quran.com/4/142))
- > And what prevents their expenditures from being accepted from them but that they have disbelieved in Allah and in His Messenger and that they come not to prayer except while they are lazy and that they do not spend except while they are unwilling. ([9:54](https://legacy.quran.com/9/54))

The above verses further show that hypocrisy can be a reason for not acceptance of good deeds. While Allah says about the prayer:

> Recite, [O Muhammad], what has been revealed to you of the Book and establish prayer. Indeed, prayer prohibits immorality and wrongdoing, and the remembrance of Allah is greater. And Allah knows that which you do. ([29:45](https://legacy.quran.com/29/45))

The prayer is an opportunity for the believer to talk and get close to his Creator which one shouldn't miss as Allah says:

> Indeed, I am Allah . There is no deity except Me, so worship Me and establish prayer for My remembrance. ([20:14](https://legacy.quran.com/20/14))

Therefore and due to what was quoted before Allah warns us saying:

> So woe to those who pray (4)
>   [But] who are heedless of their prayer - (5)
>   Those who make show [of their deeds] (6)
>   And withhold [simple] assistance. ([107:4-7](https://legacy.quran.com/107/4-7))

And similarly as the prayer is a duty on every Muslim (who is able to perform it) one must also follow the other duties and prohibitions like refraining from eating pork or drinking alcohol or approaching a foreign woman except for the purpose of marriage and refraining from sexual intercourse with a woman who is not once wife.